# What is a good book for ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation

The question is sujestive, I need to know what are good books for learning ordinary differential equations but in a deep mathematical framework. I need names of books that do not focus just on solving particular equations but develop the strong theory around them.

Comment: Ordinary (edited, thanks).

Comment: Is this to be a first course in D.E., or can it assume the student has already had a year of elementary D.E.? Often the deeper probing of a subject comes *after* an initial exposure to it so the student doesn't struggle with basic concepts while focusing on the advanced aspects.

Comment: I already had a course on ODEs and it was all about solving equations, as a mathematics student I think it is important to know the subject more formally.

Comment: I answered the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/757023/25554)

Answer (score 1):

To get a feel for the subject beyond basic computations, I'd recommend *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos* by Hirsch and Smale

Now, for a fully rigorous ODE course, I'd look to *Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations* by Coddington and Levinson.