# Good book for an introduction to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I've looked at differential equations, but nothing past what you would learn in Calculus I and II (slope fields, separation of variables, etc.). Is there a good book out there which provides a comprehensive introduction while not being too superficial? I checked out some other questions like this one and found *Differential Equations With Applications and Historical Notes*, which looks very cool, but I just want to make sure it is the best one to get before I get it. Thanks!!

Comment: Here's [my review of the book you mentioned](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/757023/25554), which I loved, and which made a huge impression on me; I can honestly say that it changed my view of a large part of mathematics.  My own undergraduate differential equations class used Boyce and DiPrima, which I found dull.

Comment: @MJD Is "Differential Equations With Applications and Historical Notes" a real intro course, or does it assume the reader already has some knowledge of ODEs?

Comment: It it a real intro course, assuming only a knowledge of calculus.

Comment: However, I would not want to say it was "the best one to get".  Different books are right for different people. A good way to find out is to check out a copy in the library and read the first chapter.