# Applications of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm trying to explain to a friend the power of differential equations in modelling math stuff. Does anyone have some really engaging/"juicy" examples? I looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757007/best-book-for-differential-equations) and found some good ones, for example:

> A smooth football having the shape of a prolate spheroid 12 inches long and 6 inches thick is lying outdoors in a rainstorm. Find the paths along which the water will run down its sides.

Answer (score 2):

[Discovering a planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbain_Le_Verrier#Discovery_of_Neptune) should be a good example. To develop a bit: the orbits of planets are predicted by differential equations (Newton's laws). The observed movement of planet Uranus did not *exactly* fit the predictions (there was a very small discrepancy). A mathematician (well, two, actually), took this on and put the following hypothesis: the planet was perturbed by a nearby, yet-unknown, planet. He did *lots* of computations, solved *more* differential equations, and emerged with the possible position of the unknown planet. He mailed a friend at an observatory with the said position. There was indeed a new planet at this place.