# Need help on books on diff. equations/geometry and theoretical computer science

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, differential-geometry, computer-science, book-recommendation

I am looking for recommendation of 3 different books on the following topics:

**1.Differential Equations**

-Ordinary diff. equations

-Vector field, transport equations

-Equation of wave and heat

-Use of Fourier series in solving differential equations.

**2.Logical components and architecture of the computers**

-Logic ports and synthesis of boolean functions

-Completion of operations (adders, multipliers)

-Memory completion/usage, interconnections (BUS)

-Assembly programming, data path, control transfers with wired controllers

**3.Differential geometry of curves and surfaces**

-Parametrized curves

*tangent, arc length, length, curvature and torsion.

*Envelope of a family of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$, involutes, caustics.

*Properties such as:

isoperimetry: find hugging curves given maximum length area.
rotation number and the integral of curve, deformation invariance, convex curves.

-Parametrized surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

*Examples, a normal, elements of a surface

*Curves on the surface, principal curvatures, mean curvature.

*Practical use such as:

Can a planisphere can truthfully represent the earth?

Being able to distinguish a rugby ball, football and a saddle; seen up close, not far away!

Depending on the time available, describe the relationship with the geometry of films and

soap bubbles.

---

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326375/looking-for-a-logically-coherent-book-for-the-self-study-of-differential-equatio/364835#364835).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book "Elementary Differential Geometry" by Barret O'Neill book is located on archive.org and is free, Link: https://archive.org/details/ElementaryDifferentialGeometry

There are older books on Differential Geometry at Archive.org also , some of the older books are excellent, although the approach doesn't generally use the exterior calculus.

Answer (score 1):

For the Differential Equations, I suggest 

*Differential Equations* by *Boyce*